# Transfer array from Php to jQuery via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am generating an array `$array` of dates in an external `.php` file which have this format `2014-01-10`(this is Jan).

What i want to achieve is transfer this array to jquery in order to use in a Ajax success callback function.

When i print_r the array in the `.php` file i get:

```
Array ( [0] => 2013-12-10 [1] => 2013-12-10 [2] => 2013-12-11 [3] => 2013-12-12 [4] => 2013-12-12 [5] => 2013-12-12 [6] => 2013-12-16 [7] => 2013-12-16 [8] => 2013-12-16 [9] => 2013-12-16 [10] => 2013-12-17 [11] => 2013-12-17 [12] => 2013-12-17 [13] => 2013-12-17 [14] => 2013-12-18 [15] => 2013-12-18 [16] => 2013-12-18 [17] => 2013-12-19 [18] => 2013-12-19 [19] => 2013-12-20 [20] => 2013-12-20 [21] => 2013-12-20 [22] => 2013-12-20 [23] => 2013-12-20 [24] => 2013-12-20 [25] => 2013-12-23 [26] => 2013-12-23 [27] => 2013-12-27 [28] => 2013-12-27 [29] => 2013-12-27 [30] => 2013-12-27 [31] => 2013-12-27 [32] => 2013-12-27 [33] => 2013-12-30 [34] => 2013-12-30 [35] => 2013-12-30 [36] => 2013-12-30 [37] => 2013-12-31 [38] => 2014-01-03 [39] => 2014-01-05 [40] => 2014-01-07 [41] => 2014-01-07 [42] => 2014-01-08 [43] => 2014-01-08 [44] => 2014-01-08 [45] => 2014-01-08 [46] => 2014-01-08 [47] => 2014-01-08 [48] => 2014-01-08 [49] => 2014-01-08 [50] => 2014-01-09 [51] => 2014-01-09 [52] => 2014-01-09 [53] => 2014-01-09 [54] => 2014-01-09 )
```

What i tried is in the  `.php` file :

```
$tried = implode(",", $array);    
echo $tried;
```

And then in my `.js` file the jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/expire.php',
        data: { expired: true },
        success: function(data) {
            takis = data.split(',');
        }
    });
});
```

But my problem is when the array from the php file is empty the `takis.length` is 1 while it should be zero. Is there any other way to transfer the array without imploding like using `dataType` or something? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Transfer it as a JSON, it will be easier to parse in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I use for this kind of coding - is to have php arrange variables into JSON code by this command on php-sided script:

```
$json=json_encode($yourquery);
```

and it'll fire off the array to jQuery at callback function, and it'll process the JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

now you should be able to access as a standard Java Script Object in the javascript similar to this

```
data.0.blah
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
$tried = json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple in your php file you must have something like this:

```
$array = Array ( '2013-12-10', '2013-12-10', '2013-12-11', '...' );
$array = Array( 'data' => $array );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And your javascript script must be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/expire.php',
    data: { expired: true },
    success: function(response) {
        takis = response.data;
        console.log( takis ); // show you an array

    }
    });
});
```